# Dynamic form from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

Im building a website using php, using a mysql database.

The user can log various things, and should be able to select which things he wants to log from an table. But i cant figure out the smartest way to do this.

Let's say i have an logging_types table, containing type_id, type_name.
By default, the user cant log anything. First they have to go to the settings where they will be presented with a logging_type and a checkbox, giving the user the ability to select what he wants to log.

In the main table, "Logs", i would have one field for each logging type.

In the users table, i would also need to have one field for each logging type here, with YES/NO or int to make it possible for the user to select what he wants to log.

Is there any other way, avoiding all these fields in the logs and users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really hard to answer as though you seem to know what you mean, you haven't really put much in the question.  It is also a bit off-topic for SO where you are expected to show a bit of code.

Nonetheless, here goes with a couple of nags first:

1. Users hate having to tick boxes.

   If you want your users to love you (and your site) try hard to make it intuitive.  Lay your tables out neatly and allow users to click and type in the appropriate boxes.
2. Never trust user supplied data.

   If your data is going to be used in a db as you suggest, then you need to be sure that the data is clean and safe.  Use JS to ensure the correct type of data is entered and make sure that PHP is used properly (use prepared statements) to sanitise the data before it is accepted.  Remember that it does not take much effort to fake input to get round any client side checking - NEVER trust user data.

Most of this type of input is done with the html SELECT entity.  A combobox with multiple options is presented. vis:

Select Datatype Here.    Enter data here.

This works really well if you have several types of data, all of which need the same amount of data in a similar format.  It falls down if the entry forms need to be radically different, though even then it can be done, you just have to hide or add some form elements (it's a lot easier to hide ones you don't need BTW)

You could also offer a tabbed/folder view if you only have say 3 or 4 different tables or forms.

Why don't you have a look and see what others are doing that is similar to what you are trying to achieve.  If you like it a lot, work out how they did it and copy it.  It is most unlikely that doing so will breach any copyright or patent.

Ask yourself how easy your system will be to use, is it intuitive?  will my user have a nasty steep learning curve, or does it just work easily? will it work well with a touch-screen device and stubby fingers? Could I adapt it to work with one?

Why not try another question but be specific.  Post the code you are working on and explain where it is or is not working.  Say more rather than less.  Trust me, you will not be giving away any secrets it wouldn't take one of the uber-geeks here more than 20 seconds to work out anyway!

Comment: I know what i want, but i'm having some problems explaining it. 
I'll start and ask a new question when i got a more specific question to ask.